# Refactoring a method to make it faster?

Tags: c#, foreach, refactoring

I have a stored procedure which is able to retrieve rows from a DB (generally 2500+) which executes and finishes fairly fast. This information is collected and read using a `DBReader` as follows:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("GetTestResults", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", _testrunID));
command.CommandTimeout = 0;
connection.Open();
DBReader rdr = new DBReader(command.ExecuteReader());
AlertItem newAlertItem;
while (rdr.read())
{
    //Populate new alert item
    newAlertItem = new AlertItem(rdr.getInt("TestRunMetricID"), rdr.getString("Type"), rdr.getString("Name"),
            rdr.getDouble("Value"), rdr.getString("Machine_Name"), rdr.getString("ExpectedProfile"),
            rdr.getInt("MetricID"), rdr.getString("Alias"), rdr.getString("GroupName"),
            rdr.getString("AlertTypeName"), rdr.getDouble("Green"), rdr.getDouble("red"),
            rdr.getString("CounterName"), rdr.getString("PlatformName"), rdr.getInt("PlatformEnv"), rdr.getInt("InstanceID"));

    //Get all alerts associated to test run metric
    newAlertItem.associatedAlerts = GraphingService.GetAssociatedAlertTypes(newAlertItem.alertTypeName, db.TestRunMetricRepo.getByID(newAlertItem.testrunmetric).Alerts.ToList());
    allAlerts.Add(newAlertItem);
}
```

This also runs fairly fast, the bottleneck is located at `GraphingService.GetAssociatedAlertTypes()`; this accepts a list (`allAlerts`) and returns a new list omitting whatever the `selectedAlert` was:

```
public static List<AssociatedAlertData> GetAssociatedAlertTypes(string selectedAlert, List<Alert> allAlerts)
{
    List<AssociatedAlertData> additionalAlerts = new List<AssociatedAlertData>();
    if (allAlerts != null)
    {
        foreach (Alert alert in allAlerts)
        {
            if (!alert.AlertRanking.AlertType.Name.Trim().Equals(selectedAlert))
                additionalAlerts.Add(new AssociatedAlertData(alert.AlertRanking.AlertType.Name.Trim(), ReturnAlertCategory(alert).ToString(), Math.Round(alert.Value, 2)));
        }
    }
    return additionalAlerts;
}
```

`GraphingService.GetAssociatedAlertTypes()` is greatly increasing the method execution time however we're struggling to speed up this method. How could we go about refactoring this method?

Comment: I dont know if Linq is faster, but it might be worth trying?

Comment: And what is actually time consuming in that method? It seems it's a simple loop. Maybe this "db.TestRunMetricRepo.getByID(newAlertItem.testrunmetric).Alerts.ToList()" is time consuming really?

Comment: @MarkPhillips We've done Linq too which turned out to be slightly slower.

Comment: what does the ReturnAlertCategory function do? plus why don't you trim and round directly in your sql query?

Comment: @Evk Good shout, we will check that out. Could well be that's the bottleneck!

Comment: @FranckNgako That just returns a string with either "Acceptable", "Warning" or "Critical"

Comment: @Novastorm ok. i think @Evk is right. the way your code is done you are querying your database in every loop step, which means open a connection => release the connection  => and other stuffs. so retrieve all your `db.TestRunMetricRepo` first and then use the in memory result for your further computation

Comment: @FranckNgako Great thank you so much for putting that into context! I'll give that a go :)

Comment: As a note - connections are usually pooled, so there is no "open connection - release connection" cycle - already opened connection is taken from pool and then put back to the pool. Still first is good to know if it's really that line which is time consuming.